# Spread function in R with multiple fields which constitute the key

Tags: r, dplyr, grouping, summarize

Im working to transform my table in this way so i can join it on another table. Here is a sample of what my initial table looks like:

```
df1 <- data.frame(ID = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),
                  date=c('2021-11-01', '2021-11-01', '2021-11-02','2021-11-01',
                         '2021-11-01', '2021-11-02','2021-11-01', '2021-11-01', '2021-11-02'
                         ),
                  event_name = c('a', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'b','a', 'b', 'c'),
                  Time_duration = c(1, 3, 5, 9, 2, 4, 1, 6, 8))
```

And this is an example of how I'd like the data to look after spreading it:

```
df2 <- data.frame(ID = c(1,1, 2,2, 3,3),
                  date=c('2021-11-01', '2021-11-02',
                         '2021-11-01', '2021-11-02',
                         '2021-11-01', '2021-11-02'
                         ),
                  event_A_duration_sum = c(4, 0,
                                       9, 0,
                                       1,0),
                  event_B_duration = c(0, 0,
                                       2, 4,
                                       6,0),
                  event_C_duration = c(0, 5,
                                       0, 0,
                                       0,8))
```

In my final table, I need to have the data grouped by (ID, Date); a unique identified for my final table would be both the ID and date. Each ID and date can have multiple events of the same type, for instance.

I hope this makes sense. Should I concatenate my identifiers and then split them back, after? Or is there a better way to do this using DPLYR?

Cheers, appreciate any help.

Comment: Try using `pivot_wider` from `tidyr`, such as: `pivot_wider(df1, id_cols = c(ID, date), names_from = event_name, values_from = Time_duration, values_fn = sum, values_fill = 0, names_prefix = "event_duration_")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library(data.table)

dcast(data.table(df1), 
ID + date ~ event_name,value.var = 'Time_duration',
 fun.aggregate = sum)

Key: <ID, date>
      ID       date     a     b     c
   <num>     <char> <num> <num> <num>
1:     1 2021-11-01     4     0     0
2:     1 2021-11-02     0     0     5
3:     2 2021-11-01     9     2     0
4:     2 2021-11-02     0     4     0
5:     3 2021-11-01     1     6     0
6:     3 2021-11-02     0     0     8
```